# jsonrpc4j: how to get List<SomeObject> from server?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to get a list of objects AccountData from my JSON-RPC server using [jsonrpc4j](https://github.com/briandilley/jsonrpc4j).

Here is code:

```
class AccountData {
    public Integer id;
    public Double accDeposit;
    public Double accCredit;
    public String accPerson;
    public String accAddressCity;
    public String accAddressStreet;
    public String accAddressBuild;
    public String accAddressApt;
    public Date accRegDate;
    public String accPersonPassport;
    public String accPersonPhone;
    public String accPersonEmail;
    public String accComments;
    public String accLogin;
    public String accPassword;
}

public void initialize() {

    try {
        JsonRpcHttpClient client = new JsonRpcHttpClient(new URL("http://localhost:8032/api"));

        try {
            List<AccountData> accountData = Arrays.asList(client.invoke("getUserAccount", new Object[]{}, AccountData.class));

            System.out.println("Method invoked");

            if (accountData != null) {
                for (AccountData data : accountData) {
                    System.out.println("login=" + data.accLogin);
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And I'm getting an exception:

```
> com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.HttpException: null
com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcHttpClient.invoke(JsonRpcHttpClient.java:166)
com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcHttpClient.invoke(JsonRpcHttpClient.java:121)
com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcHttpClient.invoke(JsonRpcHttpClient.java:132)
```

My JSON-RPC server returns result correctly, I've tested in python/php clients. Single results (non-array) works correctly too in Java.

Comment: Always post the complete, entire stack trace. Also show us some sample JSON data from your service.

Comment: Here is server reply sample: {'id': 0, 'result': [{'accDeposit': 100.0, 'accComments': 'test account', 'accPersonPassport': 'FR8382', 'accAddressStreet': None, 'accPersonEmail': 'john@johndoe.john', 'accPassword': 'test', 'accPersonPhone': '+70717654321', 'id': 8, 'accPerson': 'John Doe', 'accAddressCity': 'test city', 'accRegDate': '2016-07-11', 'accLogin': 'john', 'accCredit': 0.0, 'accAddressBuild': '1', 'accAddressApt': '18'}], 'jsonrpc': '2.0'}

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you posted is not valid. Try it at http://jsonlint.com/
You should use double quotes instead of single quotes and also None should be in double quotes too:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "result": [{
        "accDeposit": 100.0,
        "accComments": "test account",
        "accPersonPassport": "FR8382",
        "accAddressStreet": "None",
        "accPersonEmail": "john@johndoe.john",
        "accPassword": "test",
        "accPersonPhone": "+70717654321",
        "id": 8,
        "accPerson": "John Doe",
        "accAddressCity": "test city",
        "accRegDate": "2016-07-11",
        "accLogin": "john",
        "accCredit": 0.0,
        "accAddressBuild": "1",
        "accAddressApt": "18"
    }],
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

Comment: It's printed result in python client. Quotes doesn't mean any. So, can I map my result (array of objects) in Java to my ArrayList<AccountData> using jsonrpc4j?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AccountData[].class`

`

```
try {
    JsonRpcHttpClient client = new JsonRpcHttpClient(new URL("http://localhost:8032/api"));

    try {
        List<AccountData> accountData = Arrays.asList(client.invoke(
            "getUserAccount", 
            new Object[]{}, 
            AccountData[].class
        ));

        System.out.println("Method invoked");

        if (accountData != null) {
            for (AccountData data : accountData) {
                System.out.println("login=" + data.accLogin);
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`